# Avoiding 'for loop' for inner product computation using bsxfun

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices `A` and `B` with size of `[n, m]` and want to evaluate the inner product of the ROWS of both matrices.
I can use a `for` loop like;

```
 C = ones(kk,1);
for kk = 1:1:n
     C(kk) =   A(kk,:) * B(kk,:)
end
```

I want speed up the algorithm using `bsxfun` for example, but I don't know how.

Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `bsxfun`. Try the following:

```
sum(A.*B, 2) %// multiply element-by-element and then sum for each row
```

The above assumes you only want row 1 of `A` times row 1 of `B`; row 2 of `A` times row 2 of `B`, etc. If you want all combinations, use

```
A*B.'
```

By the way, your code doesn't work as it stands. It should be

```
C = ones(n,1);
for kk = 1:1:n
     C(kk) =   A(kk,:)*B(kk,:).'; %'// or
     %// C(kk) = dot(A(kk,:),B(kk,:)) %// or
     %// C(kk) = sum(A(kk,:).*B(kk,:))
end
```

Comment: I am an idiot. ok this works perfectl and it is much more perforant.

Comment: Is this the fastest method?

Comment: @phil2k14 Yes as it is only 1 function call (no loops). That is optimised for Matlab. Trust the 28k user.

Comment: @phil2k14 It's probably fast, yes; but sometimes depending on matrix size one method or other may be fastest. So: try yourself with your actual matrices